# How to create Framework7 side panel in normal vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, html-framework-7

I'm working with Vue+F7.

Is it possible to create new `side panel` in Vue, according to my scenario I need something like when app open the first page will come with one `left side panel`. Now when the user logged in I need to another side panel rather than the first one, because the content I would like to place is different.

If possible can anyone tell me how to create that panel in my example.vue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can simply make both panels and show them conditionally based on the `loggedIn` boolean. with v-show this is very easy. check these out:

[v if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

[v else if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else-if)

[v show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show)

Comment: How can I variate the content of the panel now?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component where you sent a Json with the menu data.

For example:

```
{[    
    {"name":"name_route1", "route":"@/miRuta1.vue"},
    {"name":"name_route2", "route":"@/miRuta1.vue"},   
    {"name":"name_route3", "route":"@/miRuta1.vue"}  
]}
```

This way you would have the same component (you would use the same panel) but dynamically you would pass the elements that it is going to mount.